# Организация сборки проекта через Makefile на C

Tags: c, makefile, сборка

Как организовать рекурсивную сборку проекта с помощью Makefile? Может стоит изменить файловую структуру проекта? В общем интересно услышать любое мнение.

Модель проекта:

```
.
├── ASCII_EsqSq
│   └── ASCII_EsqSq.h
├── libcalc
│   ├── calc.c
│   ├── calc.h
│   ├── calc.test.c
│   └── Makefile
├── libstr
│   ├── str.c
│   ├── str.h
│   ├── str.test.c
│   └── Makefile
├── Makefile
```

Доп. информация: 
Для сборки **libcalc** необходима **libstr**. Причем **libcalc** будет использоваться для сборки конечного приложения. Сборка будет идти в папку **./build**.

P. S. Свои неработающие прототипы Makefile'ов кидать не буду, так как считаю, что они будут только мешать.

**UPD:**

Меня просили добавить конкретики.

1. Можно ли как-то упростить сборку?
2. Возможно ли как-нибудь при создании библиотеки libcalc.a засунуть в нее библиотеку libstr.a? Чтобы не писать -L$(DIR1) -lcalc -L$(DIR2) -lstr
3. Я может быть что-то делаю не так?

***libcalc/Makefile***

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) -Wall -Wextra -Werror



ifneq ($(BUILD_DIR),)
BUILD_DIR:= $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(CURDIR)))
else
BUILD_DIR:= $(CURDIR)/build
endif

ifeq ($(INCLUDE_DIR),)
INCLUDE_DIR = $(CURDIR)/..
endif

OBJ_DIR= $(BUILD_DIR)/obj

#Флаги в debug режиме
CDEBUG= -g

#Флаги для valgrind
VFLAGS= --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes 

# Подключаемые библиотеки
LIBS=-L$(BUILD_DIR) -lcalc -L$(BUILD_DIR)/libstr -lstr
STR_LIBF= $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/libstr,libstr.a)

#Исходные файлы 
SRC= calc.c 
OBJ= $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(SRC:%.c=%.o))
CALC_LIB= calc
CALC_LIBF= $(BUILD_DIR)/lib$(CALC_LIB).a

# Unit тесты
TEST_SRC= calc.test.c
TEST_OBJ= $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(TEST_SRC:%.c=%.o))
TEST_EXE= $(BUILD_DIR)/calc.test
TEST_LIBS= -lcheck -lsubunit 
TEST_LIBS+= $(LIBS)




.PHONY: all valgrind debug clean clang $(CALC_LIB) test

all: $(TEST_EXE)

debug: CFLAGS+= $(CDEBUG)
debug: all

test: $(TEST_EXE)
    $(TEST_EXE)

$(CALC_LIB): $(CALC_LIBF)

$(CALC_LIBF): $(OBJ) $(STR_LIBF)
    ar rc $(CALC_LIBF) $(OBJ)
    ranlib $(CALC_LIBF)

export BUILD_DIR INCLUDE_DIR
$(STR_LIBF):
    $(MAKE) -C $(INCLUDE_DIR)/libstr str

$(TEST_EXE): TEST_LIBS +=  $(LIBS)
$(TEST_EXE): $(TEST_OBJ) $(CALC_LIBF) $(STR_LIBF)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TEST_OBJ) -o $(TEST_EXE) $(TEST_LIBS)



$(TEST_OBJ): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

valgrind: debug
    CK_FORK=no valgrind $(VFLAGS) ./$(TEST_EXE) 

clang:
    clang-format -i $(SRC) $(TEST_SRC)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

***libstr/Makefile***

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -I$(INCLUDE_DIR) -Wall -Wextra -Werror


ifneq ($(BUILD_DIR),)
BUILD_DIR:= $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(CURDIR)))
else
BUILD_DIR:= ./build
endif

ifeq ($(INCLUDE_DIR),)
INCLUDE_DIR = ..
endif

OBJ_DIR= $(BUILD_DIR)/obj

#Флаги в debug режиме
CDEBUG= -g

#Флаги для valgrind
VFLAGS= --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes 

# Подключаемые библиотеки
LIBS= -lm -L$(BUILD_DIR) -l$(STR_LIB) 

#Исходные файлы 
SRC= str.c 
OBJ= $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(SRC:%.c=%.o))
STR_LIB= str
STR_LIBF= $(BUILD_DIR)/lib$(STR_LIB).a

# Unit тесты
TEST_SRC= str.test.c
TEST_OBJ= $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(TEST_SRC:%.c=%.o))
TEST_EXE= $(BUILD_DIR)/str.test
TEST_LIBS= -lcheck -lsubunit 
TEST_LIBS+= $(LIBS)




.PHONY: all valgrind debug clean clang $(STR_LIB) test

all: $(TEST_EXE)

debug: CFLAGS+= $(CDEBUG)
debug: all

test: $(TEST_EXE)
    $(TEST_EXE)

$(STR_LIB): $(STR_LIBF)

$(STR_LIBF): $(OBJ)
    ar rc $(STR_LIBF) $(OBJ)
    ranlib $(STR_LIBF)

$(TEST_EXE): TEST_LIBS+=$(LIBS)
$(TEST_EXE): $(STR_LIBF) $(TEST_OBJ) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TEST_OBJ) -o $(TEST_EXE) $(TEST_LIBS) 


$(TEST_OBJ): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(TEST_LIBS)

$(OBJ): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : %.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(LIBS)

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

valgrind: debug
    CK_FORK=no valgrind $(VFLAGS) ./$(TEST_EXE) 

clang:
    clang-format -i $(SRC) $(TEST_SRC)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

***./Makefile***

```
BUILD_DIR= $(CURDIR)/build
INCLUDE_DIR= $(CURDIR)

export BUILD_DIR 
export INCLUDE_DIR
all:
    $(MAKE) -C libcalc

clean:
    rm -rf $(CURDIR)/build
```

Все собирается.
После вызова **make** в ***.*** получаю

```
.
├── ASCII_EsqSq
│   └── ASCII_EsqSq.h
├── build
│   └── libcalc
│       ├── calc.test
│       ├── libcalc.a
│       ├── libstr
│       │   ├── libstr.a
│       │   └── obj
│       │       └── str.o
│       └── obj
│           ├── calc.o
│           └── calc.test.o
...
```

Comment: рассмотрите использование CMake

Comment: Без примеров ваших `Makefile` выглядит так будет вы просите полностью написать код за вас. Добавьте и напишите что работает неправильно, что вы уже пробовали (если пробовали) и что хотите, но не знаете как сделать. Спасибо.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, сделал, как вы и просили. И спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Ingvar, посмотрю. Спасибо за ответ.